# Execute threads concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I implemented a producer/consumer model using a queue.The program description follows:

- producer takes 4 files from a certain folder and puts each file's absolute path into a queue
- the consumers (in my case: 4 ) take the filepath from the queue and do sth. with it (for example: give it to an application for executing)

Here, my code:

```
queue_condition = threading.Condition()
shared_queue = Queue(maxsize=4)

def consumer(condition):
            with condition:
                 # wait as long the queue is empty
                 while shared_queue.empty():
                       logger.info("[%s] - waiting for elements in queue ..." % threading.current_thread().name)
                       condition.wait()
                 else:
                       # take the selected path from the queue
                       item = shared_queue.get()
                       logger.info("[%s] - has selected the file %s" % (threading.current_thread().name, item))

                       # copy it to another place
                       start_application(item)


                       shared_queue.task_done()
                       logger.debug("[%s] has finished its task" % threading.current_thread().name)

#############################################################################

def producerCM(condition):
            logging.debug('Starting selection ...')

            with condition:

                 # as long as queue is not full
                 # start picking a file
                 while not shared_queue.full():
                       # select the file
                       filename = pick_file()
                       selectedFilePath = basepath + "\\" + filename

                       item = selectedFilePath
                       logging.debug("Selected File: " + selectedFilePath)
                      shared_queue.put(item)

                      logging.debug("Notifying consumer threads that the queue is ready to consume ..")
                      condition.notifyAll()



threads = [threading.Thread(target=consumer, args=(queue_condition,)) for i in range(4)]

for thread in threads:
                thread.setDaemon(True)

[thread.start() for thread in threads]

prod = threading.Thread(name='producer_task_thread', target=producerCM, args=(queue_condition,))
prod.setDaemon(True)
prod.start()

[thread.join() for thread in threads]
```

My problem is that, for example, Thread1 takes one file and after the its operation, Thread2 starts taking the other file from the queue.
But what I want is that they should start at the same time. So, why Thread2 need to wait for Thread1 ?

Here, an output:

```
2017-05-21 13:48:35,053 - [Thread-1] - waiting for elements in queue ...
2017-05-21 13:48:35,055 - [Thread-2] - waiting for elements in queue ...
2017-05-21 13:48:35,055 - [Thread-3] - waiting for elements in queue ...
2017-05-21 13:48:35,055 - [Thread-4] - waiting for elements in queue ...
2017-05-21 13:48:35,056 - Starting selection...
2017-05-21 13:48:35,056 - Selected File: C:\Users\k1rk1r\Desktop\AvIo\samples\aecore.dll
2017-05-21 13:48:35,058 - Selected File: C:\Users\k1rk1r\Desktop\AvIo\samples\aecrypto.dll
2017-05-21 13:48:35,058 - Selected File: C:\Users\k1rk1r\Desktop\AvIo\samples\aebb.dll
2017-05-21 13:48:35,059 - Selected File: C:\Users\k1rk1r\Desktop\AvIo\samples\aecore.dll
2017-05-21 13:48:35,059 - Notifying fibonacci_task threads that the queue is ready to consume ..
2017-05-21 13:48:35,059 - [Thread-1] - has selected the file C:\Users\k1rk1r\Desktop\AvIo\samples\aecore.dll
Command is: C:\Program Files\FRISK Software\F-PROT Antivirus for Windows\fpscan.exe -r -d 100 -z 99 C:\Users\k1rk1r\Desktop\AvIo\samples\aecore.dll
2017-05-21 13:48:35,059 - [Thread-2] - has selected the file C:\Users\k1rk1r\Desktop\AvIo\samples\aebnd.dll
Command is: C:\Program Files\FRISK Software\F-PROT Antivirus for Windows\fpscan.exe -r -d 100 -z 99 C:\Users\k1rk1r\Desktop\AvIo\samples\aebnd.dll
```

For example: How can I tell Thread 2 that is not necessary to wait for the completion of Thread1 ? Because Thread2 could take another item from the queue and process the execution of the application with selected file.

Comment: Very nice. I wish I could upvote again. If you you don't receive a good answer in two days, drop me a comment and I will put up a bounty here. And you want to delete all these comments :-)